# RegEx for finding words between dots

Tags: python, regex

I am new to RegEx and I want to use regular expression to find words between dots.

For example, the text is something like:

```
abc.efg.hij.klm.opq.
```

I tried with below RegEx:

```
\.(\w+)\.
```

It only show me 2 matches:

```
.efg.
.klm.
```

Why am I getting this result?

Here is the link to the RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/pqMN8t/1/

Comment: do you need something more like "\.*\w+\."?

Comment: For me, this is not a duplicate of the one marked above. Not exactly. Well, the reason is the same but the solution isn't. Sweeper's answer below has provided me the exact solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only shows two matches because the regex engine will not match what it has already matched. After matching `.efg.`, it won't match the dot before `hij`, because that dot has already been matched (the dot after `efg`).

One way to fix this is to not match the dots and use lookaheads and lookbehinds instead:

```
(?<=\.)\w+(?=\.)
```

This way, the dots won't get matched.